# remplazar {{variable}} por su valor

Tags: javascript, html

hola e estado viendo algunos tutoriales de javascript y me gustaria saber como puedo remplazar un texto en `<div>{{varible}}</div>` por el valor que contenga esa variable pero sin usar frameworks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="texto">{{nombre}}</div>
    <div id="texto">{{apellido}}</div>
    <div id="texto">{{numero}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

y el resultado fuera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="texto">jhon</div>
    <div id="texto">smith</div>
    <div id="texto">123456</div>
</body>
```

Comment: esa sintaxis parece fuertemente de algunos frameworks, usas alguno o solo JavaScript?

Comment: Puedes echarle un vistazo a [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 3):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
let nombre = "jhon";
let apellido = "smith";
let numero = "123456";
// funcion de remplazo      
function test() {
   // seleccionamos todos los elementos del documento
   // y lo asignamos a la varible el
   for (let el of document.body.getElementsByTagName('*')){ 
                // omitimos los tagName script
                if (el.tagName === "SCRIPT") continue;
                try {
                    // obtenemos el texto del elemento
                    // remplazamos lo que este dentro de {{}}
                    // evaluamos la expresion con `eval` para obtener el valor
                    // de dicha variable "si existe!"
                    // remplazamos el texto por el resultado obtenido.
                    el.innerText = eval(el.innerText.replace(/\{\{(.+)?\}\}/, '$1'));
                } catch (e) {
                    if (e instanceof SyntaxError)
                        console(e.message);
                    else
                    // si no existe la varibale la marcamos undefined
                        el.innerText = 'undefined';
                }
            }
        }
// llamamos a la funcion  
test();
```

```html
<div id="texto">{{nombre}}</div>
<div id="texto">{{apellido}}</div>
<div id="texto">{{numero}}</div>
```

> **nota:** utilizamos `try{} catch{}` para evitar que nos salte un error en caso de que no este definida la variable o no se puede evaluar la expresion